# How to know the path of file that was opened in each mdi subWindow?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have the following `MDI application`:

[image]

Each `sub Window` has content of different file.
When we want to save the content of active window, thus, we want to know the path of file that opened in active window.

**How to know the path of the file that opened in active `subWindow` or any other `subWindow` ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the path as a user property on the widget, using `QObject::setProperty`, and then retrieve it using `QObject::property`. `QMdiSubWindow` has no concept of an open file. It's just an MDI widget. Someone might use it to show today's weather, and not the contents of any particular file.

Comment: I think your answer simpler and more clarity.

Answer (score 1):

It's entirely demanded to your application.

A QMdiSubWindow just holds a QWidget. Of course, having a file path it's not a requisite for q QWidget. In my [pqSource](https://github.com/CapelliC/loqt/tree/master/pqSource) component, I use different classes, and I have a MdiHelper class, implementing a typed 'collection' of subwindows:

```
template<class T>
QList<T*> typedSubWindows() const
{
    QList<T*> l;
    foreach (auto w, mdiArea()->subWindowList())
        if (auto s = qobject_cast<T*>(w->widget()))
            l << s;
    return l;
}
```

Some of these widgets have a file path...